# Swift 3.0 Couldn't get required object pointer (substituting NULL): Couldn't load 'self' because its value couldn't be evaluated

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, lldb

when executing this code:

```
public enum Month : String {
    case January  = "JAN"
    case February = "FEB"
    case March = "MAR"
    case April = "APR"
    case May = "MAY"
    case June = "JUN"
    case July = "JUL"
    case August = "AUG"
    case September = "SEP"
    case October = "OCT"
    case November = "NOV"
    case December = "DEC"

    func toDate() -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MMM.yyyy hh:mm a"
        let dateString = "01.\(self.rawValue).2016 12:00 PM"
        return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

when I try printing "po dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!" where the crash is happening:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   error: warning: couldn't get required object pointer (substituting NULL): Couldn't load 'self' because its value couldn't be evaluated
>
> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100c551ec).
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

This is only happening on my iPhone 6s running iOS 10.1.1 and not happening on any of the simulators and on a device running iOS 9.x.x

Anyone has any idea whats going on and what "Couldn't load 'self' because its value couldn't be evaluated" means.

I tried it in a new project with just this code and I can still reproduce the error.

Even hardcoding the month, without the self part gives the same error:

`let dateString = "01.NOV.2016 12:00 PM"`

**UPDATE**

For anyone coming to this the proper way to construct a Date object is this:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var components = DateComponents()
components.day = 1
components.month = month
components.year = year
components.hour = 12
components.minute = 00

let date = calendar.date(from: components)!
```

Comment: Verified your code on 10.0 and its working fine for me.

Comment: @Sharpkits I don't have a 10.0 device, tried it only on 10.1.1

Comment: > `let calendar = Calendar.current`. Not really advising using `current` calendar here, if you have specific date, i guess you know the calendar you were using it. But `current` calendar can differ from it, and 1st day of 11th month of 2016th year in Islamic calendar won't be same as in Gregorian calendar, and difference is huge.

Comment: @user28434 so how would I handle constructing a date when have only a month? The day and time part are not really relevant to the app, we are working with months exclusively

Comment: @Simon, well your month names looks like Gregorian calendar names, so use `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming to this later, the proper way to construct a Date object when you only have the month and year is this:

```
var components = DateComponents()
components.day = 1
components.month = month
components.year = year
components.hour = 12
components.minute = 00

let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
```

Answer (score -3):

Your code will give totally incorrect results in less than two months time. And it will crash if the user's locale is not English speaking.

Comment: I think that you are right about the not being English. Can you elaborate more on that? Will the problem be that the months are in English and the locale will try to load localized versions of the months?